# What happened to the Dai Li during Kuvira's time?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

We see the Dai Li a lot in ATLA, but they actually do appear as well in TLOK. I recall they 1st appears in TLOK s3 in train conscripted airbenders, but I forgot what happened to them in TLOK s3. Probably they became unemployed?

Anyhoo, I don't recall they were mentioned in TLOK s4. Maybe there's a mention in the comics?

Answer (score -1):

Well, according to the [Avatar Wiki](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Dai_Li), their last appearance is in Season 3: "Long Live the Queen", and the rest of the page doesn't say anything about them after that episode, so it seems that's where their story ends.

Comment: OP is interested in what happened to them *after* that

Comment: @Valorum - Added more to say "It seems their last appearance was also their last mention."

Comment: Where their story ends (in the TV show) (according to the wiki). It's possible that they're mentioned in the the follow-on comics or one of the various prose novels that have been released